# Using POST requests to Solr from SolrNet

Tags: post, solr, solrnet

Is it possible to send data to Solr using POST instead of GET? I use SolrNet and a Windsor container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You have to write a decorator around `ISolrConnection` that POSTs instead of GETs.

Installing the decorator is very easy in Windsor:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<ISolrConnection>()
    .ImplementedBy<PostSolrConnection>()
    .Parameters(Parameter.ForKey("serverUrl").Eq(serverURL)));
container.AddFacility("solr", new SolrNetFacility(serverURL));
```

[I blogged exactly about this some time ago](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/12/customizing-solrnet.html) (decorator code included)

**UPDATE**: PostSolrConnection is now part of the SolrNet library as `SolrNet.Impl.PostSolrConnection`

Comment: in ur specified post I think there will be infinite recursion in method public string Post(string relativeUrl, string s), am i right

Comment: @AhsanIqbal : no, there is no infinite recursion.